# How to install latest GCC/Mingw in Windows 7 32 bit Operating System?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, 32-bit, mingw

I know that I can download MinGW from Cygwin, MSYS, but I saw that they don't have the latest GCC compiler. And that's why I searched in Google that how to get latest GCC in windows, and I found [winlibs.com](http://winlibs.com)  has the latest GCC. But it doesn't have full GCC. It has no `opt, etc, licenses,` etc directories. And this is why I can't setup it for VSCode. So, how to get latest GCC in Windows 7 32 bit operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 is no longer supported.

Comment: How can I download it in any upper version of windows tho...

Comment: Cygwin has a 32bit version, with full version of GCC compiler for Cygwin and Mingw64

Comment: Does it contain gcc/g++ 11/latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin 32 bit

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/gcc-src.html

has the version 11 available as test

```
10.2.0-1   stable
11.1.0-0.1 test
```

so you can install that

Comment: Does this mean Gnu C compiler or gnu compiler collection in that gcc? And I don't even know how to install gnu compiler collection via cygwin. So, can you help?

Comment: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages